# Difficult integrals, do they converge, show there's no dependence on parameters.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

I am trying to figure out whether these integrals:

a) 
$$\int_{\mathbb R^2}{{\rm d}\xi
\over
\left\vert\vphantom{\Large A}\,\log\left(\left\vert\,x - \xi\,\right\vert\right)
-\log\left(\left\vert\,y - \xi\,\right\vert\right)\,\right\vert\ \left\vert\,x - \xi\,\right\vert\ \left\vert\,y - \xi\,\right\vert}$$

b) $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}{{\rm d}\xi
\over
\left\vert\vphantom{\Large A}\,\log\left(\left\vert\,x - \xi\,\right\vert\right)
-\log\left(\left\vert\,y - \xi\,\right\vert\right)\,\right\vert^{1/3}\ \left\vert\,x - \xi\,\right\vert\ \left\vert\,y - \xi\,\right\vert}$$

Converge, and if they do, show that the result does not depend upon $x,y \in \mathbb R^2$.

I am completely stumped. Would appreciate any ideas / hints in the right direction.

I would like to clarify that this is not a homework assignment, but rather an exercise to prepare for an exam.

Comment: Where did you find these monsters ?

Comment: @Claude Leibovic Worksheet my teacher gave me...no solutions included.

Comment: Please, when you get the answer, add it to your post. Thanks & cheers :)

Comment: First, split the integrals to get rid of the absolute values, then, use substitutions $u = \log(x-\xi)$.